# How do I convert an ApiFuture to a ZIO Task?

Tags: firebase, scala, zio

I am working with Firebase so I have a lot of return types of type `ApiFuture<A>`. I'd like to turn them into a `Task[A]` to work with ZIO effects.

Answer (score 1):

We can create a method to convert all of them using Typeclasses:

```scala
trait EffectUtils[F[_]] {
  def toEffect[A](a: F[A]): Task[A]
}

object EffectUtils {

  implicit val apiFuture: EffectUtils[ApiFuture] = new EffectUtils[ApiFuture] {
    override def toEffect[A](a: ApiFuture[A]): Task[A] = Task.effectAsync[A]( cb =>
      ApiFutures.addCallback(a, new ApiFutureCallback[A] {
        override def onFailure(t: Throwable): Unit = cb(Task.fail(t))
        override def onSuccess(result: A): Unit = cb(Task.succeed(result))
      })
    )
  }

  implicit class ApiFutureOps[A](f: ApiFuture[A]) {
    def toEffect(implicit instance: EffectUtils[ApiFuture]) = instance.toEffect(f)
  }
}
```

Now, when we make an API request and want to convert the result to a ZIO type, it's easy:

```
import EffectUtils._

object App {
  // calling a Firebase function
  val record: Task[UserRecord] = firebase.getInstance().auth().getUserByEmailAsync(email).toEffect
```

Comment: Why all the overhead, just add the extension method directly to `ApiFuture`

Answer (score 1):

For ZIO v2.0+, the function `Task.effectAsync` isn't available anymore.

But the solution is even simpler than the Nimrod's answer:

```
import com.google.api.core.*
import zio.*

extension [A] (apifuture: ApiFuture[A]){

  def toTask: Task[A] = ZIO.async( handler =>
    ApiFutures.addCallback(apifuture, new ApiFutureCallback[A] {
        override def onFailure(t: Throwable): Unit = handler(ZIO.fail(t))
        override def onSuccess(result: A): Unit = handler(ZIO.succeed(result))
      })
  )
}
```